# Adjusting SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT product_description.name, product.quantity,product.price
    FROM product
    INNER JOIN product_description
    ON product.product_id=product_description.product_id
    ORDER BY product_description.name
```

I need to incorporate a few more tables,  I have tried the following but I am unsure how I will extend my ON beyond one pair.

**Error: (ON line)**

```
SELECT product_description.name, product.quantity,product.price,product_option_value_description.name
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_description, product_option_value_description
ON product.product_id=product_description.product_id=product_option_value_description.product_id
ORDER BY product_description.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a separate join for each table you want to join on

```
...
JOIN Table1 ON ...
JOIN Table2 ON ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT pd.name,p.quantity,p.price,povd.name
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id=pd.product_id
INNER JOIN product_option_value_description povd ON p.product_id=povd.product_id
ORDER BY pd.name
```